# I can't run php on CLI

Tags: 16.04, php, php-cli

When I install it again it says php is already the newest version.
when I run `php -v` the out put is this:

```
The program 'php' can be found in the following packages:
* php7.0-cli
* hhvm
Try: sudo apt install <selected package>
```

when runing `type php`:

```
bash: type: php: not found
```

When I run `whereis php` the out put is this:

```
$ whereis php
php: /usr/bin/php.old /usr/bin/php7.0 /usr/lib/php /etc/php /usr/share/php7.0-common /usr/share/php7.0-intl /usr/share/php7.0-json /usr/share/php /usr/share/php7.0-zip /usr/share/php7.0-mcrypt /usr/share/php7.0-mysql /usr/share/php7.0-readline /usr/share/php7.0-opcache /usr/share/php7.0-xml /usr/share/php7.0-mbstring /usr/share/php7.0-gd /usr/share/man/man1/php.1.gz
```

I have looked for solutions but none of them worked.

Comment: /usr/bin/php7.0 ???

Comment: Please post the output from when you try to run `php`, including the exact command you use. Also post the output of `type php`; this is more useful than `whereis php` or `which php`. You can [edit] your question to add info. By the way, welcome to Ask Ubuntu!

Comment: @wjandrea just did. please i need a solution asap.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you have `php7.0-cli` installed, but no `/usr/bin/php`. The latter is normally a symlink managed by the alternatives system. You can show the status of that by issuing the following command:

```
$ update-alternatives --display php
php - automatischer Modus
  beste Version des Links ist /usr/bin/php7.0
  Link verweist zur Zeit auf /usr/bin/php7.0
  Link php ist /usr/bin/php
  Slave php.1.gz ist /usr/share/man/man1/php.1.gz
/usr/bin/php7.0 - Priorität 70
  Slave php.1.gz: /usr/share/man/man1/php7.0.1.gz
```

If this shows different output on your computer this is probably not set correctly. You can try to run `update-alternatives --auto php` and test again if a) `php -v` works now and b) `update-alternatives --display php` now produces output similar to the above.

If this didn't help you can manually set the alternative: `update-alternatives --set php /usr/bin/php7.0` and test again.

Answer (score 1):

I've never used PHP, so take this with a grain of salt:

It looks like `/usr/bin/php` got renamed to `php.old`. I'm guessing if you run `readlink /usr/bin/php.old` it will point to `/usr/bin/php7.0`. If so, you can un-rename it by running

```
sudo mv /usr/bin/php.old /usr/bin/php
```

Otherwise, you could create a new `/usr/bin/php`:

```
sudo ln -s php7.0 /usr/bin/php
```

Or reinstall the whole package:

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall php7.0-cli
```